# When io util is relatively high, will Linux read and write hard disks return EIO?

Tags: linux, hard-disk, io, read-write

When input/output util is relatively high, will Linux read and write hard disks return EIO?

Comment: Hi! Welcome here! In the context of hard drives, I don't know what EIO is. What does that abbreviation refer to?

Answer (score 1):

Having high device utilisation is not an error. Each physical I/O request makes a syscall, and the request is added to a separate queue for each independent device. For some media types, requests can be re-ordered to optimise usage.

Queue lengths are generally limited because any process/thread with a queued request will not get scheduled (so does not exit from the syscall), and will not be able to issue another request.

Some slow devices (e.g. sockets) can return errno=EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable) which advises the process to retry the remaining part of the transfer. This normally happens when the process receives a signal.

Answer (score 0):

Why would it?

For reference, from `include/uapi/asm-generic/errno-base.h`:

```
#define EIO      5  /* I/O error */
```

Comment: Ahhh yeah that makes sense. Not every day can be my brightest day! Have an upvote, please.